# avoid minimizing when the model is evaluate tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've a **Tensorflow graph**(a neural network), inside of which i've defined this variable:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(Joint_Loss)
```

when i feed my graph using the method

```
o = sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                     y: batch_y,}
```

i run one step of optimization of the weights in the graph(weights of my net are updated).

Now if i call after the previous call another run **with the same graph** (that has optimizer variable), without specify **optimizer** as fetches arg, like this:

```
  loss = sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                     y: batch_y,}
```

the minimization step is done or not(weights are updated)? and if it's done how i can avoid it with tensorflow conditional statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a network is not updated. Since your `loss` doesn't depend on `optimizer` in computational graph, tensorflow will omit the execution of this operation.

Comment: thus weights are update only when i specify as fetches arg a variable that depends by the optimizer correct?

Comment: Yes. Or the optimizer operation itself.